# How to build ckeditor5 balloon block from source?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

There are [five ckeditor5 ready-made builds](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/index.html) available: classic, inline, balloon, balloon-block and document. I would like to use the balloon-block layout, but I want to build it from source (as is recommended) for integration into my Vue 2.x app (with webpack and Vue CLI 3). [The docs for building from source](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html) use the classic editor as an example, and instead of using the pre-built package `@ckeditor5/ckeditor5-build-classic`, it says to import the source package `@ckeditor5/ckeditor5-editor-classic` and use that as a base to which you can add all the plugins you want.

The balloon layout has its own source package `@ckeditor5/ckeditor5-editor-balloon` which presumably can be used similarly, but I can't find any source package for balloon-block. If I'm supposed to use the `...editor-balloon` package as a base, are there any docs I can use that will show me how to build my own balloon-block from source?

I've just learned that the hidden toolbar accessed from the gutter is actually a plugin calle `BlockToolbar`, so presumably I do just have to use the `editor-balloon` package as the source base and include/configure that plugin. If someone else doesn't provide a more complete example with sample config, I'll post an answer with my own solution when I have something. In the meantime, [the docs here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/toolbar/blocktoolbar.html) for the block toolbar plugin has lots of info on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui', which should already be a dependency of '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-balloon' itself and import the plugin 'BlockToolbar' and use it in your 'create()' method call. Like so:

```
import BalloonEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-balloon/src/ballooneditor';
import { BlockToolbar } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';

BalloonEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
        plugins: [BlockToolbar, Essentials, Paragraph], // BlockToolbar added here!
        toolbar: ['bold', 'italic'],
        blockToolbar: ['heading', 'paragraph', 'heading1', 'heading2', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList'],
    });
```